# Can someone tell me how to createa hook or an addon for whmcs

Tags: hook, add-on, whmcs

When I create an addon, the name, description aren't displayed. On the oficial site I couldn't find the all needed information

Comment: Please enter more details and share what you have done so far ?

Comment: I need to create an addon which should show the status of payment for a separate category of services, and when I create the addon with the name     partners.php onto partners folder with code

Comment: function clientadding() {
 command = "addclient";
 $adminuser = "developer";
 $values["firstname"] = "Test";
 $values["lastname"] = "User";
 $values["companyname"] = "WHMCS";
 $values["email"] = "demo@whmcs.com";
 $values["address1"] = "123 Demo Street";
 $values["city"] = "Demo";
 $values["state"] = "Florida";
 $values["postcode"] = "AB123";
 $values["country"] = "US";
 $values["phonenumber"] = "123456789";
 $values["password2"] = "demo";
 $values["customfields"] = base64_encode(serialize(array("1"=>"Google")));
 $values["currency"] = "1";
localAPI($command,$values,$adminuser);

Comment: Did you read this page for docs? http://docs.whmcs.com/Addon_Module_Developer_Docs